# jspm hot reloading install - command not found after global install

Tags: sockets, npm, jspm

i try to install the hot reload module of jspm using the chokidar-socket-emitter. Installation works like charme, but after that it is not possible to start the watch task as described here: http://jspm.io/0.17-beta-guide/hot-reloading.html

Here is my install log:

XXXXXMacBookPro:dasding xxxxxx$ sudo npm i -g chokidar-socket-emitter
\

> fsevents@1.0.12 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/chokidar-socket-emitter/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents
>   node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

[fsevents] Success: "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/chokidar-socket-emitter/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v14-darwin-x64/fse.node" is installed via remote
chokidar-socket-emitter@0.3.1 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/chokidar-socket-emitter
├── socket.io@1.4.6 (has-binary@0.1.7, debug@2.2.0, socket.io-parser@2.2.6, socket.io-adapter@0.4.0, engine.io@1.6.9, socket.io-client@1.4.6)
└── chokidar@1.5.2 (path-is-absolute@1.0.0, inherits@2.0.1, glob-parent@2.0.0, async-each@1.0.0, is-binary-path@1.0.1, is-glob@2.0.1, readdirp@2.0.0, anymatch@1.3.0, fsevents@1.0.12)

**XXXXXMacBookPro:dasding xxxxxx$ chokidar-socket-emitter**

**bash: chokidar-socket-emitter: command not found**

XXXXXMacBookPro:dasding xxxxxx$

Does anyone has any idea why he is unable to find the command? i have no idea how to fix this, global installs always used to work without any problem.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Ok, in case someone faces the same problem - my current node.js installation was unable to handle the latest version of chokidar-socket-emitter, so a lower version was installed, but the docs refered to the latest version, so there never was a command that could have been found. after updating my node.js installation everything worked like charme.